# Animate the writing of each letter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm very new to animation, and I couldn't find any way to animate the writing of each letter of a word but instead of that what I got is each letter getting typed. But I want my animation to show how we write each letter(eg: Splash Screen of Netflix). In Flutter(Dart).

Answer (score 1):

how about using this [animated_text_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit)

Comment: I've seen that too but didn't find what I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for a late response in case you still haven't figure it out you should try Rive animations and then implementate it to your project. That worked for me. But keep in mind if your are new in this be patient it takes time to get the hand of it. Keep